# Finding value of checkbox in dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So, I'm writing some JS which dynamically creates some DOM elements. Below is a structure of the elements created:

```
<div class='list_item' key='1'>
    <p>Hello, World!</p>
</div>

<div class='cont' key='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='test'/>
</div>
```

When an event is triggered, I want to loop through all `.list_item`, and find their corresponding `.cont`, using the `key` attribute as an identifier. I want to find the value of the `.cont > input[type="checkbox"]`.

Here's my code so far:

```
$('.list_item').each(function() {
    var x = $('.cont[key="' + $(this).attr('key') + '"]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
    console.log(x);
});
```

Instead of getting a `true` or `false` response, my code throws `undefined` as its result. What can I do to my code to get the response I want (the value of the checkbox)?

Thanks

Comment: here: `var x = $('cont` you missed a dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You forgot to close the attribute selector
2. You forgot the `.` before `cont` in the class selector

So:

```
$('.list_item').each(function() {
    var x = $('.cont[key="' + $(this).attr('key') + '"]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
// ------------^--------------------------------------^
    console.log(x);
});
```

Note that you can do that with a single selector rather than `find`:

```
$('.list_item').each(function() {
    var x = $('.cont[key="' + $(this).attr('key') + '"] input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
    console.log(x);
});
```

Example:

```js
$('.list_item').each(function() {
  var x = $('.cont[key="' + $(this).attr('key') + '"] input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<div class='list_item' key='1'>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</div>

<div class='cont' key='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='test' />
</div>

<div class='list_item' key='2'>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</div>

<div class='cont' key='2'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='test' />
</div>

<div class='list_item' key='3'>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</div>

<div class='cont' key='3'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='test' checked/>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just missed '.' before class selector

```
$('.list_item').each(function() {
var x = $('.cont[key="' + $(this).attr('key') + '"]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: That's *half* the problem, yes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I see that your selector is wrong. The class dot is missing. Try with this:

```
$('.cont[key="' + $(this).attr('key') + '"')
```

Comment: That's *half* the problem, yes. :-)